# How can I tell if my DNS A record has updated successfully?

Tags: domain-name-system, cloudflare

I migrated a site from one host to another host. The records are held with Cloudflare.

I changed the IP address from the old IP address to the new one in the A record. When I use a tool such as `whatsmydns` it shows neither IP address but an IP address that is owned by Cloudflare.

How can I tell if it has successfully moved?

Comment: Maybe give is the actual name and we can check it for ourselves. As it stands, your question lacks the information we would need to give you any kind of insightful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudflare's default TTL is 5 minutes. When you go to change your server's IP address in Cloudflare, you are actually not change the public facing A record. The public A record remains the same. Cloudflare just knows to route traffic to the new IP address on the backend.

I would suggest reviewing your access logs on the new server to ensure web traffic is getting to the new server.